# Multiple open tabs in Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

is there a way to get firefox to display more than one tab at the same time? It'd come handy if I could have two pages open side by side, especially with a widescreen monitor. Can this be done in a single firefox instance or do I have to open two instances and place them next to each other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the ["split browser extension"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4287).

> You can split browser infinitely, as
>   many as your RAM and your screen
>   allow. Enjoy split and split to your
>   heart's content!
>
> Drag and drop is available to load
>   links, bookmarks, and so on, into
>   split browser. If you drag the toolbar
>   of split browser, you can load the
>   page in another split browser.
>
> Split browsers can be closed by their
>   closebox. "File" > "Close All Split
>   Browser" closes all of them at once.

[image]

Comment: Smacked in the image, so everyone directly believes it's awesome ;-)